# Can't connect LDAP over SSL

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to use LDAP over SSL to create webpage to reset AD user password. As I understand changing password requires SSL.

I have added `AD Certificate Services` using **add roles and features in Server Manager**. Then I am able to connect it using `LDP.exe` (even I tried to use **search function** and it works).

[image]

But I cannot connect using PHP. This is my source code:

```
<?php
    $ldap_dn = "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=nurda,DC=local";
    $ldap_password = "";
    $server = 'ldaps://nurda.local:636';

    putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never');
    $ldap_con = ldap_connect($server) or die ("Can't connect");
    ldap_set_option($ldap_con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);

    if(ldap_bind($ldap_con, $ldap_dn, $ldap_password)){
        echo "Bind successfull";
    }else {
        echo "Invalid user/pass or other errors!";
    }
?>
```

This code outputs **Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind server: Can't contact LDAP sever**

> If I try using `$server = 'ldap://nurda.local';` it binds succesfull

I am using Windows Server 2012 r2 and XAMPP

> Does it mean I cannot connect using PHP, If I can connect through ldap.exe?
>
> What else I exactly need to do? I can add any additional information for troubleshooting

More information how I enabled LDAP:

- uncommented `extension=ldap` in php.in
- copied libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll into C:/xampp/php

Comment: Have you tried to get the last LDAP error? https://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-error.php - you should also take a look at the User Contributed Notes, it has an example that you can use

Comment: @KoenHollander when I put ldap_error() after `ldap_connect` it shows **Success**, when I put it after `ldap_bind` it shows **Can't contact LDAP server**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LDAPS not connecting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890462/ldaps-not-connecting-with-php) (maybe this question will be helpful), although there is no marked-answer

Comment: @KoenHollander thanks, it helped